# MySql functions with kohana ORM

Tags: mysql, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I'm bit confuse how to convert my query :

```
> SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `total_logs`, `userlog`.* FROM `user_log` AS
> `userlog` WHERE `user_id` = '31' AND date(`date_created`) =
> '2012-04-30'
```

to Kohana 3.1 ORM? currently i m using :

```
> $isLoged = ORM::factory('Userlog')->select(array('COUNT("id")',
> 'total_logs'))
>                 ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
>                 ->and_where('Date(date_created)', '=',  date('Y-m-d'))
>                 ->find_all();
```

unfortunately above one is giving error :(

> Database_Exception [ 1054 ]: Unknown column 'Date(date_created)' in
>   'where cla....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'Date(date_created)'` string will be escaped and treated as a column name, unless you will first pass it to `DB::expr()`. Thus instead of `'Date(date_created)'` try the following:

```
DB::expr('Date(date_created)')
```

See [the documentation on `DB::expr()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/DB#expr).